# How to make a table from text file?

Tags: tables, loops, datatool

I have a text file, where every line is a question. I want to take this file and make a questionnaire with it, so I need a loop that takes each line and makes a table line with it, along with a True/False cell, until the end of the file. I've found these two solutions, one without using any package and the second using `pgffor`

Solution 1:

```
% read input file line by line
\newread\file
\openin\file="media/questions.txt"
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
        \read\file to \fileline
        % write line
        \fileline
    \repeat
\closein\file
% end loop
```

Solution 2:

```
\foreach \question in {\input{media/questions.txt}}
{
    \question
}
```

This works file as long as I just print the text to the document. Of course, by doing this, the questions are unformatted and not inside a table, so I tried to insert the loops inside a `tabular`

Solution 1:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
% read input file line by line
\newread\file
\openin\file="media/questions.txt"
    \loop\unless\ifeof\file
        \read\file to \question
        % write line
        \question  & True & False \\\hline
    \repeat
\closein\file
% end loop
\end{tabular}
```

Solution 2:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
\foreach \question in {\input{media/questions.txt}}
{
    \question & True & False \\\hline
}
\end{tabular}
```

However, both these codes do not work: the errors are as follow

```
tex/test-2.tex:15: Argument of \loop has an extra }.
tex/test-2.tex:15: leading text:         \question &
tex/test-2.tex:15: Paragraph ended before \loop was complete.
tex/test-2.tex:15: leading text:         \question &
tex/test-2.tex:16: Extra \fi.
tex/test-2.tex:16: leading text:     \repeat
```

```
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing control sequence inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
tex/test-2.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
tex/test-2.tex:28: leading text: }
```

Both the `&` and `\\` seem to make the loop stop before going to the next line. How can I build the table line inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working example: (replace test.txt with your file ofc)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{xparse}%

\makeatletter%
\NewDocumentCommand{\preparetable}{m}{%
    \bgroup%
    \gdef\usetable{}%
    \let\hline=\relax%
    \newread\file%
    \openin\file=#1\relax%
    {\endlinechar=-1% else you will have empty spaces/lines at the end... 
        \loop\unless\ifeof\file%
        \read\file to\tmp%
        \ifx\tmp\@empty\else%
            \xdef\usetable{\usetable\tmp&True&False\\\hline}%
        \fi%
        \repeat%
    }%
    \closein\file%
    \egroup%
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}%
    \preparetable{test.txt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}%
        \usetable%
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}%
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the `datatool` package. The `.txt` file with the questions is uploaded to a database, a column is added for the answers, and then all the rows are inserted into a table.

(Trivia questions selected from internet sites.)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{datatool}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{LotOfQuestions.txt}
%%https://www.opinionstage.com/blog/true-or-false-questions/    
The Big Apple is a nickname given to Washington D.C in 1971.    
Peanuts are not nuts!
People may sneeze or cough while sleeping deeply.
Emus can’t fly.
Electrons move faster than the speed of light.
Light travels in a straight line.
The Mona Liza was stolen from the Louvre in 1911.
You make decisions based on logic.
There’s nothing like reading a good book.
You’re doing exactly what you dreamed of doing as a child.
You’re planning to embark upon an academic career.
There are three rivers in Saudi Arabia.
The Great Wall of China is visible from space. 
Australia is wider than the moon.
Venus is the hottest planet in the solar system.
Cows sleep standing up.
Japan has square watermelons.
I think, carefully, before I say something.
Buying a used car will help you minimize depreciation.
\end{filecontents*} 

\DTLsetseparator{|}

\newcommand{\MarkTrueFalse}{\bigcirc\hspace*{2em}\bigcirc}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<MARKS for true/false

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Questions}]{questionsdb}{LotOfQuestions.txt}  

\DTLforeach{questionsdb}{% to add a new column
\Questionx=Questions}{%
\DTLappendtorow{TRUEFALSE}{\MarkTrueFalse}}     
    
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}% expand the rows
    \caption{Mark TRUE or FALSE}\bigskip
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \bfseries Question &
        \bfseries True/False        
        \DTLforeach{questionsdb}{% loop over the rows
            \Questionx=Questions,\TrueFalse=TRUEFALSE}{%
            \\% start new row
            \Questionx & \TrueFalse }
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

A more decorated table: horizontal rule, vertical expansion and question numbering. Squares centered to the baseline for the answers.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  

\usepackage{datatool}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{booktabs} % lines
\usepackage{amssymb}% more symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}% scale

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{LotOfQuestions.txt}
%%https://www.opinionstage.com/blog/true-or-false-questions/    
The Big Apple is a nickname given to Washington D.C in 1971.    
Peanuts are not nuts!
People may sneeze or cough while sleeping deeply.
Emus can’t fly.
Electrons move faster than the speed of light.
Light travels in a straight line.
The Mona Liza was stolen from the Louvre in 1911.
You make decisions based on logic.
There’s nothing like reading a good book.
You’re doing exactly what you dreamed of doing as a child.
You’re planning to embark upon an academic career.
There are three rivers in Saudi Arabia.
The Great Wall of China is visible from space. 
Australia is wider than the moon.
Venus is the hottest planet in the solar system.
Cows sleep standing up.
Japan has square watermelons.
I think, carefully, before I say something.
Buying a used car will help you minimize depreciation.
\end{filecontents*} 

\DTLsetseparator{|} 
\newcounter{qnumber}
    
\newcommand{\MarkTrueFalse}{\bigcirc\hspace*{2em}\bigcirc}

\renewcommand{\MarkTrueFalse}{% large centered squares
 \raisebox{-1ex}{\scalebox{2}{\square}}\hspace*{2em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\scalebox{2}{\square}}
}
    
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Questions}]{questionsdb}{LotOfQuestions.txt}  

\DTLforeach{questionsdb}{% to add two new columns
\Questionx=Questions}{%
\DTLappendtorow{TRUEFALSE}{\MarkTrueFalse}
\stepcounter{qnumber}
\DTLappendtorow{NUMBER}{ \theqnumber.}
}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% expand the rows
    \caption{Mark True \textbf{OR} False}\bigskip
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{clc}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries \large Question} & \bfseries \large True/False    
        \DTLforeach{questionsdb}{% loop over the rows           
        \Qnumber=NUMBER,\Questionx=Questions,\TrueFalse=TRUEFALSE}{%
        \DTLiffirstrow{\\\midrule}{\\}%         
        \Qnumber&\Questionx & \TrueFalse }% end of loop     
        \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, but the one from @Yumina is simpler and does not require any additional packages ;) I have upvoted yours, but without 15 rep I don't think you'll see it